# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm having a problem in saving data to two tables of my database which is `PurchaseOrder` and `PurchaseOrderLineItems` using the generic view of Django the `CreateView`.
I'm getting this error: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)` and I don't know where in the code is the error.
I'm getting the data from a html table ( it has checkbox per row ) that is generated by another table called `Masterlist` that will save in `PurchaseOrderLineItems`.

Here's what I tried by searching of how can I save the data. I created a post function inside the CreateView class.

```
class PurchaseOrderCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = PurchaseOrder
    fields = ['project_site', 'supplier']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.prepare_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['object_list'] = Masterlist.objects.all()
        return super(PurchaseOrderCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        po = PurchaseOrder.objects.all()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            get_list = request.POST.getlist('checks[]')

            for item in get_list:
                get_id = Masterlist.objects.filter(item[0])

                save_to_pol = PurchaseOrderLineItems(item_no=get_id.item_no, description=get_id.description, dimension=get_id.dimension, unit=get_id.unit, quantity=get_id.quantity, cost=get_id.cost, total=get_id.cost * get_id.quantity, po_fk=pk)
                save_to_pol.save()

        return super().post(request)
```

Error Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/lastmile/purchaseorder/new/

Django Version: 2.1.4
Python Version: 3.7.1
Installed Applications:
['users.apps.UsersConfig',
 'lastmile.apps.LastmileConfig',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/workstationthreesoftwaredeveloper/JXMTSI/Projects/Office/Application/Web-Application/Django/environ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/workstationthreesoftwaredeveloper/JXMTSI/Projects/Office/Application/Web-Application/Django/environ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/workstationthreesoftwaredeveloper/JXMTSI/Projects/Office/Application/Web-Application/Django/environ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/workstationthreesoftwaredeveloper/JXMTSI/Projects/Office/Application/Web-Application/Django/environ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/workstationthreesoftwaredeveloper/JXMTSI/Projects/Office/Application/Web-Application/Django/environ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py" in dispatch
  52.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/workstationthreesoftwaredeveloper/JXMTSI/Projects/Office/Application/Web-Application/Django/environ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/workstationthreesoftwaredeveloper/JXMTSI/Projects/Office/Application/Web-Application/Django/Application/ERP/lastmile/views.py" in post
  57.                 get_id = Masterlist.objects.filter(item[0])

File "/Users/workstationthreesoftwaredeveloper/JXMTSI/Projects/Office/Application/Web-Application/Django/environ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/workstationthreesoftwaredeveloper/JXMTSI/Projects/Office/Application/Web-Application/Django/environ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  844.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/workstationthreesoftwaredeveloper/JXMTSI/Projects/Office/Application/Web-Application/Django/environ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  862.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "/Users/workstationthreesoftwaredeveloper/JXMTSI/Projects/Office/Application/Web-Application/Django/environ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1263.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "/Users/workstationthreesoftwaredeveloper/JXMTSI/Projects/Office/Application/Web-Application/Django/environ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1287.                     split_subq=split_subq,

File "/Users/workstationthreesoftwaredeveloper/JXMTSI/Projects/Office/Application/Web-Application/Django/environ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1161.         arg, value = filter_expr

Exception Type: ValueError at /lastmile/purchaseorder/new/
Exception Value: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

What I want is when the user fills up the fields for the `PurchaseOrder` and then checked the items in the html table (generated by `Masterlist`) and hit the button, it will save the the checked items in the `PurchaseOrderLineItems`

Comment: your `super()` call is not correct...

Comment: what do you mean not correct sir @Enix ? Is there any missing code there?

Comment: you should call `super(PurchaseOrderCreateView, self)` instead of `super()`.

Comment: I tried it, but still got the same error. I have an UpdateView, with the same `return` but no error.

Comment: @KarloLee Can you add the error traceback?

Comment: @JPG , Hi sir. Is it the `Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view` ? Sorry I'm beginner on this.

Comment: Yeah, It is. You should add your error traceback  (if any) in questions. It would help others to understand the problem :)

Comment: @JPG , thank you sir. I already added it.

Comment: ok. Can you check the value of **`item[0]`** in your code? (before this line `get_id = Masterlist.objects.filter(item[0])`)?

Comment: @Enix. You really don't need to do that in Python 3. The call is correct as-is

Comment: @JPG , the value is 1 and 2 the primary key the two items.

Comment: What is the type of `get_list` and What data it holds?

Comment: You should read about Django query set to know how to build the filter. e.g. `MyModel.objects.filter(name='Jack').filter(id__in=[1,2])`.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters